# Quickly checking whether two line segments are from the same line

Tags: c#, geometry

I have two edges, both of which are made up of 2  3-dimensional points, forming a line segment.

Is there a relatively quick way of checking whether both of the line segments part of the same line?

Comment: are you referrring to geometric lines (which extend infinitely)?

Comment: @NayeemMansoori He specifically said line segments, so no.

Comment: If two lines have unequal slope they will intersect in a a point. If two lines have equal slope, they are either disjointly parallel and never intersect, or they are the same line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first segment has end points A,B , and second segment has end points C,D. Both segments belong to the same line, if

```
AB x AC = AB x AD = 0 (vector product)
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. Could you elaborate a little more on what `AB` means?  Is it the vector created by point `a` to point `b`?

Comment: This is the cross product, yeah?

Comment: Yes, this is the cross product. AB is vector from point A to point B, `AB=B - A`

Answer (score 0):

How to do it depends on how your segments are represented, but an idea would be:

- check they are collinear ( ie **no intersection** )
- Length of the candidat must be smaller or equal
- then check for start or end being on the potential container